# Every link clicked on iOS device is opening a single app

Tags: ios, react-native, url, deep-linking

one of our iOS app users has reported that every time they click on a link it opens our app even if the link is not at all related to our app. For example: if it's a instagram link, then also the browser is prompting the user to open our app instead of opening the link in instagram/default browser. how can we solve this for our user?

after uninstalling our app, all links are opening in their corresponding app / browser. But as soon as our app is installed again. all links are prompted to open in our app.

Answer (score 0):

"import {Linking} from 'react-native';"

"Linking.openURL('https://www.instagram.com/galatasaray')"

install the linking library or it may be automatically installed. if instagram is installed it opens the app directly, if not it opens it in the browser

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably linked to the deep linking configuration on iOS.

### What happen

You have registered an URL scheme which catch many url, probably something like `https://` or similar. When iOS check which app can handle https://instagram.com/id, it found that your app can display it.

This configuration is there in XCode:
[image]